# how to add names and scores in `/Tellraw`

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've looked through basically every post about this, and each of them is like 2-3 years old and do not work with Bedrock edition.

Here's the code I have, It displayed `Test x= y= z=` but does not give any actual values. The Minecraft documentation and wiki didn't have examples for these parts either.

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text": "Test", "extra":[{"selector":"@s"}]},{"text":" §ax="},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"Coords-X"}},{"text":" §ey="},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"Coords-Y"}},{"text":" §cz="},{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"Coords-Z"}}]}
```

I am fairly certain that the selector is messing up in both the scores and as a selector, but I am unsure on how I would get it to work.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or do it differently?

Comment: I had the same question, but unfortunately, it's not possible. **For now.** See this question: [How do I output a scoreboard value or a selector to chat in Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370567/how-do-i-output-a-scoreboard-value-or-a-selector-to-chat-in-bedrock-edition)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I see now, the wiki says upcoming. Well, I hope 16.1 comes out soon, thanks

Comment: PS. Be careful, Bedrock Edition version numbers change when you add/remove trailing zeros. So 1.16.1 is different from 1.16.100. Numbers after each dot follow integer rules, not decimal rules.

Comment: Also, you now have enough reputation to upvote posts you find helpful. If you found the linked question/answer helpful, please consider heading to the question/answer and upvoting it, to tell the community that it helped you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: This only works in Java edition, not Bedrock, as OP's ask is impossible in the current Bedrock edition. (Hopefully this is still useful as a guide for doing it in Java edition.)**

According to [the Commands/tellraw wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tellraw), any text you send using the /tellraw command must be a raw JSON text. [On that page,](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format) the wiki says you can store scoreboard values in JSON text like this:

> Scoreboard Value (requires resolution)
>
> - **score**: Displays a
>   score holder's current score in an objective. Displays nothing if the
>   given score holder or the given objective do not exist, or if the
>   score holder is not tracked in the objective.
> - **name**: The name of the
>   score holder whose score should be displayed. This can be a selector
>   like @p or an explicit name. If the text is a selector, the selector
>   must be guaranteed to never select more than one entity, possibly by
>   adding limit=1. If the text is "*", it shows the reader's own score
>   (for example, /tellraw @a {"score":{"name":"*","objective":"obj"}}
>   shows every online player their own score in the "obj" objective).[4]
> - **objective**: The internal name of the objective to display the player's
>   score in.
> - **value**: Optional. If present, this value is used regardless
>   of what the score would have been.

Now let's look at your code. I'm going to break it up a bit and format it like a JSON file for ease of reading.

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a {
  "rawtext":[
    {"text": "Test", "extra":[{"selector":"@s"}]},

    {"text":" §ax="},
    {"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"Coords-X"}},

    {"text":" §ey="},
    {"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"Coords-Y"}},

    {"text":" §cz="},
    {"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"Coords-Z"}}
  ]
}
```

So first, you are defining objectives. According to some Reddit posts I found, this is an example of how to do that:

> {"score":{"name":"@p","objective":"TEST"}}

Which means you are doing that correctly, so that's not the issue.

Next, I asked myself if "Coords-X", "Coords-Y" and "Coords-Z" are valid objectives. So I looked it up. It turns out you have to add these as objectives before you can use them. **Did you possibly run these commands to add the coordinates as objectives?**

> /scoreboard objectives add Coords-X dummy
>
> /scoreboard objectives add Coords-Y dummy
>
> /scoreboard objectives add Coords-Z dummy

Finally, it seems like you are trying to use **@s** to target the entity that runs the command. So you're probably trying to display the coordinates of the person who calls this command. Thus, after you define these objectives, [you may need to set up command blocks, one each for X, Y and Z, and set them with this command](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/9r9rdl/how_can_i_display_the_coordinates_of_all_the/):

> /execute as @a store result score @s Coords-X run data get entity @s Pos[0] 1

Which will keep track of the coordinates so that they can be displayed.

I have no idea if this is helpful but I hope one of these things solves your problem!

Comment: What version of Minecraft is this answer for?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I just noticed your comment on the question that proves this is impossible in OP's version of Minecraft, so I guess my answer is not really helpful. I apologize for not realizing.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 This is for Badrock edition (PE; Bedrock) unfortunately.

I already have all of the objectives set with values, but the selectors, in general, are not working for me in `tellraw` commands.

The execute command Sciborg provided is for Java Edition, as Badrock has a different format for Execute commands.

Also with the **@s** part, it works does not work with any selector, and the @s is part of a execute for the target, which applies to the limit =1 requirement.

I am not able to use the tellraw with a specific target, even if I provide its actual name, in any of the parts

Comment: @EletroMagneticInterference I realized that unfortunately after Expert told me. I apologize for providing a wrong answer as I had assumed Java commands worked in Bedrock. That's my bad.

Comment: Expert also added a comment, this is currently not possible, I missed the part in the wiki that said "upcoming", but @Sciborg Thanks!